# Serialize an object without the object's information

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I am in a situation I need to serialize only the values of the members of an object to a file.

for example, if the object contains 3 string members I would want the output of the serialization to be only this 3 strings without the serialization metadata the **Binaryformatter** adds, like the version, culture, and assembly name of the object.

One option is just to write each members of the object directly, but I want to avoid this because I have lots of classes that need to be serialize like this and I don't want to write a function that handles this differently for each class.

**Requirements:**

I want to be able to write to any type of file, I want the values of the members to be translated to bytes (into a buffer or directly into the file) and to be able to write those bytes at a specific position in the file.

Is there a way or an API of serializing only the value of the members of an object?

Comment: Do you intend to _deserialize_ it at some point?

Comment: Probably not, but if I will be in a situation I need to deserialize the object's members I will probably read each member individually.

Comment: There are any number of alternative serialization APIs; xml, json, protobuf, etc. All of those can be used without type-metadata information. But there is a lot of requirement / context missing here...

Comment: @Matan - Using reflection, you could interrogate the object, then write the data you want from the object to file. This would be generalized (you'd only have to write it once), and you could write the file in the format you wanted (vs. using existing serialization APIs). Link to Microsoft's reflection docs -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @DavidHope +1 for using reflection to _"interrogate"_ the object.

Comment: @Matan: one of your requirements is "to be able to write to any type of file"... that's pretty broad.

Comment: I meant to say that I will be able to open a file for example using a `FileStream` and to serialize to this stream.

Answer (score 1):

Matan,

Here is some code I put together for an entirely different purpose, but it takes an unknown object and serializes it into an XML file (updated to include better coding practices).

```
    void objectToXMLFile(String fn, object o)
    {
        XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter(fn, null);

        System.Type type = o.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] piList = type.GetProperties();

        textWriter.WriteStartDocument();

        textWriter.WriteStartElement("attributeList");

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in piList)
        {
            textWriter.WriteStartElement("attribute");

            textWriter.WriteStartElement("name");
            textWriter.WriteString(pi.Name);
            textWriter.WriteEndElement();

            textWriter.WriteStartElement("value");
            textWriter.WriteString(pi.GetValue(o).ToString());
            textWriter.WriteEndElement();

            textWriter.WriteStartElement("dataType");
            textWriter.WriteString(pi.PropertyType.Name);
            textWriter.WriteEndElement();

            textWriter.WriteEndElement();
        }
        textWriter.WriteEndElement();
        textWriter.WriteEndDocument();
        textWriter.Close();
    }
```

Comment: In this case, wouldn't it be safer to leverage the `XmlSerializer` with a simple `AttributeList` data model as it would better handle special cases (like values containing characters that need XML-escaping?)

Comment: For my code, yes, that would likely have been the better course of action. However, the code was presented as a example of using reflection in C#, so is still germane.

Comment: Ok I take my words back this reflection can work for my use just fine. =] I didn't know the existence of reflection at all.

Comment: unfortunately turn out this solution isn't good for me, My objects have many types of members like int and string, And at the end I need the members to be converted into bytes, reflection don't give me the best solution because now I will need a byte convertion for each member and writing each object directly is almost as good.

Comment: Could you use: ToString() to convert it to a string then write the string? Granted it would be "wasteful" of space.

Comment: Requirements aside, this code would have a very high performance cost. @David Hope, if you insist on formatting the XML by yourself, and you must do it in memory (and not to a file), at least use a `StringWriter` or a `StringBuilder`. The code you wrote would allocate a ton of strings - since `String` is immutable, every time you use += you duplicate in memory the XML you got so far.

Comment: @Ran - thanks for the advice. In this case I was just throwing something together quickly and didn't think it through. I appreciate your calling me on it.

Comment: I can't use a stringWriter because I don't want to write a number in ASCII encoding..

Answer (score 0):

If you do end up using Reflection to only write the wanted properties, you may want to consider some performance implications.

Using Reflection is slow. Reflecting the type itself has a high price, and then dynamically invoking the `PropertyInfo` by calling `PropertyInfo.GetValue` is very slow.

An alternative is to build an Expression tree that calls the properties and writes their values, and then compile this expression into an `Action`. You can cache these `Action` instances in a dictionary keyed by the `Type` of the object you are serializing, and invoke the right one when you want to serialize the object.

That would be much much faster and will also not create so much load on the GC.

Another alternative you may consider is code generation at build time - you can generate a class to serialize your target type quickly and cheaply. In some scenarios this is a good choice.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the best option, my problem is not how to store all the properties is how to serialize them..

Comment: I have many kinds of classes, the function that will "call" the properties and write their values, will be implemented differently for each class and this is what I want to avoid. I am searching for an API that will only write the values of the properties of any type of object.

Comment: @Matan, why would it be implemented differently? You can write 1 function that gets a target Type to serialize, goes over the type's properties using reflection, and generates a fast generic Action that can write the properties of an instance of this type.